# Build custom Laravel database adapter

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5.1

i am building a project with Laravel 5.1 on a Linux Server.
There are two databases one MySQL (no problem here) and MSSQL (problem here).
The point is, after a very long research, i finally get the data using mssql funtions like (mssql_query, mssql_fetch_object, etc).
My question is related to how can i build an adapter using design patterns inside Laravel architecture, and finally building a  driver.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel does support MS-SQL out-of-the-box. There's no need to write an adapter. Just configure the 'sqlsrv' connection in your config/database.php and then you have some options to use it:

**1 - Directly via DB Facade:**

```
$collection = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(...);
$collection = DB::connection('mysql')->select(...);
```

**2 - Setting Model's connection property:**

```
class Foo extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';

    ...

}
```

**3 - Changing Model's connection at runtime:**

```
$foo = new Foo;

$foo->setConnection('mysql');

$foo->bar = 'baz';

$foo->save();
```

Please refer to [Laravel's Database Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections) for more information.

However, if you still need to write an adapter for some reason, the correct way of doing it is writing a [Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers). Take a look at the implementation of [MongoDB Connector](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) as a good reference. Also, I highly recommend you reading the entire "Architecture Foundations" section in Laravel's docs, they are really helpful!

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for your answer.
The default laravel sqlsrv uses PDO function based on driver available only in Window Server.
http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php

That is why i'm using mssql functions instead, using php5-mssql driver.

I'll definitly read the Architecture Foundations to get a better idea for many ideas i want to implement.

Thanks.